# Change Default Value of Slug_Field to customslug in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-2.1

I am using Generic Views in Django 2.1.

My views get mixed because I don't know why:

urls.py:

```
path('study-abroad/<slug:slug>/', views.SubjectDetailView.as_view(), name='subject-detail'),
path('study-abroad/<slug:slug>/', views.StudylevelDetailView.as_view(), name='studylevel-list'),
```

So I think it is better to name custom slugs in order to prevent that. Like this:

urls.py:

```
path('study-abroad/<slug:subjectslug>/', views.SubjectDetailView.as_view(), name='subject-detail'),
path('study-abroad/<slug:studylevelslug>/', views.StudylevelDetailView.as_view(), name='studylevel-list'),
```

**My Question is:**

*How can I change the default value of Slug_Field to mycustomslug?* (It is slug by default in Django)

Views.py

```
class SubjectDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Programmesearch
    template_name = 'mnsdirectory/subject_detail.html'
    def slugify(value, allow_unicode=False):
        slug_field = slugify('Programmesearch.full_subject_name')


class StudylevelDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = StudyLevel
    template_name = 'mnsdirectory/study_level.html'
    def slugify(value, allow_unicode=False):
        slug_field = slugify('StudyLevel.study_level')
```

Models.py:

```
class Programmesearch(models.Model):
    full_subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SUBJECT_NAME_CHOICE)
    subjectslug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subjectslug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('SubjectDetailView', args=[str(self.id)])

class StudyLevel(models.Model):
    study_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    studylevelslug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.studylevelslug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('StudylevelDetailView', args=[str(self.id)])
```

When I try to add a new object in admin page I get an error saying

"FieldError at /admin/mnsdirectory/studylevel/add/
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: id, study_level, studylevelslug"

Comment: add slug_url_kwarg = 'subjectslug'  or slug_field='subjectslug' for your view method

Comment: @HemanthSP I tried but it doesn't work. It shows the same error.